# Video Upload with php with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My uploaded file not to move the folder but path save in mysql. what have the problem for my code how to save the video in folder, ihave already create the folder name which is test_uploads. what is exexct method to get the video in folder

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("ngo",$con);

extract($_POST);

$target_dir = "test_upload/";

$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if($upd)
{
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($imageFileType != "mp4" && $imageFileType != "avi" && $imageFileType != "mov" && $imageFileType != "3gp" && $imageFileType != "wmv")
{
    echo "File Format Not Suppoted";
} 

else
{

$video_path=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];

mysql_query("insert into video(video_name) values('$video_path')");

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$target_file);

echo "uploaded ";

}

}

//display all uploaded video

if($disp)

{

$query=mysql_query("select * from video");

 while($all_video=mysql_fetch_array($query))

 {
?>

 <video width="300" height="200" controls>
 <source src="test_upload/<?php echo $all_video['video_name']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
 </video> 

 <?php } } ?>

 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<table border="1" style="padding:10px">

<tr>

<Td>Upload  Video</td></tr>

<Tr><td><input type="file" name="fileToUpload"/></td></tr>

<tr><td>

<input type="submit" value="Uplaod Video" name="upd"/>

<input type="submit" value="Display Video" name="disp"/>

</td></tr>

</table>

</form>
```

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements

Comment: already try but result same #Jens

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code to find the error. Something like this:

```
$result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$target_file);

if($result) {
  mysql_query("insert into video(video_name) values('$video_path')");
  echo "uploaded ";       
} else {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["error"];
}
```

Comment: @AbhishekShulka What error message you got for else section

Comment: if($imageFileType != "mp4" && $imageFileType != "avi" && $imageFileType != "mov" && $imageFileType != "3gp" && $imageFileType != "wmv")
{
    echo "File Format Not Suppoted";
} 
 
else
{
 
$video_path=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
 


 
$result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$target_file);

if($result) {
  mysql_query("insert into video(video_name) values('$video_path')");
  echo "uploaded ";       
} else {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["error"];
}
 
echo "uploaded ";
 
}
 
}

Comment: there is only one problem the file not move the folder

Comment: i don't understand what the actual problem

Comment: can you give the solution for this @Saili